# make regex compatible with .NET and JS

Tags: javascript, .net, regex

Can someone help me modify this Regex pattern so that it doesn't use positive lookahead and lookbehind since these are not compatible with JS and .NET?

The idea is that I am trying to get a first match of any characters that are between "-" and "-" ie. `NY` from a string like this: DSK-NY-110. Here's what I got that works but it won't work in JS and .NET at the same time so I need something that is compatible with both:

`(?<=\-)\w+(?=\-)`

Thanks!

Comment: Use `-(\w+)-` to grab the Group 1 value.

Comment: .NET supports lookarounds

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't want to work under the assumption that there will be groups returned. Is there a way to just make it ignore the two bounding characters?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I know .NET does but this regex is shared between JS and .NET so it has to work in both.

Comment: Then your problem has no solution unless you only target ECMAScript 2018 compliant JS environments (where lookbehinds are supported, as e.g. in Chrome). I'd rather you do support groups in your solution, they are more flexible.

Comment: Perhaps split on a `-` as an alternative?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for the answer. In that case I will look into making it work with Groups. Appreciate the help!

Comment: I'd go with @WiktorStribiżew's pattern and rewrite your code to look at the first group if present or the whole match if not. If you want to make fewer assumptions about the regex engine, your code is going to have to more flexible to handle different use cases.

Comment: What about `[^-]+(?=-[^-]*$)`? JS supports lookaheads, right?

Comment: @Sweeper doesn't that only grabs the "last" match so in a string like: DSK-NY-120-A it would return "120" instead of "NY". That's why I said "first match". I can make it work with Groups by grabbing the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest approach is to rely on [**capturing groups**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and extract the submatches using appropriate code-behind.

The regex may look like

```
-(\w+)-
 |---|-> Group 1
```

and then all you need is to get the Group 1 value:

C#:

```
var groupID = 1; // It can even be user input
var result = Regex.Match(s, @"-(\w+)-")?.Groups[groupID].Value;
```

In JS:

```js
var groupID = 1, s = "Some-string-here", m;
var result = (m=s.match(/-(\w+)-/)) ? m[groupID] : "";
console.log(result);
```